# Can't send an array via Protocol.HTTP()

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

I'm trying to send a JSON file to my Node.js app via Protocol.HTTP. The file is correctly sent, but I can't access to an array. Here is the relevant code :

Client side

```
(...)
    var vectorProtocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: '/getcoords',
                    format: vectorFormat,
                    readWithPOST: true,
                    params: {
                        "code_company": "8501",
                        "data_company": [
                            {
                                "origin": "2013P00109",
                                "type": "LJ",
                                "naf": "5610A",
                            },
                            {
                                "origin": "2013P00110",
                                "type": "FJ",
                                "naf": "5481"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
(...)
```

Server side, I try to build an array with only the "origin" field of my array "data_company":

```
function getCoords(params, callback) {
      var arrOrigin = params.data_company.map(function(d) {
         return d.origin;
      });
      (...)
}
```

And I get this error :

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method "map"

It seems that my "data_company" array is not parsed. Is there a reason for that ? And a workaround ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In server side convert json type to array.

Comment: Something to be aware of is that any answers (and questions) that are shorter than about a paragraph get flagged up for review because often answers of such length provide insufficient information about what the answer is based on (experience, link to a bulletin board, etc). If you are able to edit you answer to provide some more supporting information I suspect it will be far more likely to attract some upvotes too.